# How to descibe living at foot of mountain?

Tags: grammar

Is it all right to say "I used to live in a town which is located at the feet of the mountains"or "at the foot of the mountains" .

Comment: ***Foot:*** the bottom or lower end of a space or object:
They built a house at the foot of a mountain. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foot

Comment: Go-go-gadget n-gram: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foot+of+the+mountain%2Cfeet+of+the+mountain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoot%20of%20the%20mountain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeet%20of%20the%20mountain%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either say the town was at the foot of the mountains, or in the foothills of the mountains.  "Feet" would be an incorrect usage, since the first is idiom, and the second is a term for a geological feature.

Answer (score 0):

Foothills is generally what folk say where I'm from.  Other options might include: highlands, crag edge, hillocks, fells, slope of the mountain.